# How do you aim?

Tags: yooka-laylee

Might have missed that one in the tutorial, but how do you aim when firing? I can only shoot in front of me.

Is there some kind of 1st person mode?

Comment: The tutorial for this actually comes after leaving W1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those playing with Keyboard on PC, tab allows you to aim.

Comment: Please elaborate on the second part of the question (1st person mode).

Comment: And if you're using a controller on PC?  I just clicking the right-stick on my XO controller like the other answer says works on console but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hmm you might have to look into key bindings, which I imagine you have on PC.

Answer (score 4):

Found it, on controllers, click right stick.

Tested on PS4

Comment: Also the same on Xbox One.

Answer (score 1):

On the steam controller it is ls click.  I am not sure why.  It must have something to do with the way the controller emulation is setup.

Comment: Same with the Xbox 360 controller on PC.